# What is a 'data-provider' in the context of a form in a Rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Disclaimer: this is my first serious side-project. I am a noob to rails and programming in general, but trying my best to learn.

I am trying to implement a WYSIWYG text editor into one of my forms on my rails project. Users are allowed to create "event" objects that have a "body" text_area field. Right now the description form ignores all user formatting, and I want to fix this. I'm trying to implement [Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/summernote-rails) without much luck. I'm using the Summernote-rails gem but this part of the documentation is what is giving me trouble:

"If you are not using simple_form, then simply add the data-provider="summernote" to the input field yourself."

I've researched this to no end but I can't figure it out. What is the "data-provider" and how can I implement it properly? My confusion stems from the fact that I've never seen this "data-provider" before. Is it an HTML form attribute? Is it bootstrap related? Thank you to anyone who can clarify this for me!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="well">
    <div class="form-area">
        <h3>Create an Event</h3>
        <%= form_for @event, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :image %>
                <%= f.file_field :image %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :title, "Title of the event" %>
                <%= f.text_area :title, rows: 1, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :date %>
                <%= f.text_field :date, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :time, "Start Time" %>
                <%= f.text_field :time, class: "form-control" %>

            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :body, "Include all the details about your event here." %>
                <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 10, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :category_id %>
                <%= f.select(:category_id, Category.all.map{ |f| [f.name, f.id] }, {}, { class: "form-control", id: "select" }) %>
            </div>
            <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add Summernote to this part of the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :body, "Include all the details about your event here." %>
                <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 10, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

I have followed Summernote-rails gem's instructions and my application.js looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require google_analytics
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require pickadate/picker 
//= require pickadate/picker.date 
//= require pickadate/picker.time 
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require summernote
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .


$('[data-provider="summernote"]').each(function(){
  $(this).summernote({ });
})
```

Comment: Hi Graham, I too am trying to use summernote with rails and bootstrap_form. I can't yet figure it out, using similar set-up leads to an input form not being "overtaken" by Summernote. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct, data-provider is an HTML attribute (though it has nothing to do with Bootstrap). HTML5 introduced the "data-" prefixed attributes as a convention for storing data pertaining to elements which would otherwise be relegated to class names in prior versions. Additionally, the little bit of JavaScript you wrote in application.js as per the instructions is actually a selector for setting up all objects with that specific attribute (using a custom method). All you're really doing is using a more advanced (or at least more specifically tailored) Class or Id for selection purposes.

For a basic overview of HTML5 data- attributes, see [this article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. With your explanation I was able to get this working (at least superficially :) The JS and HTML are all taken care of, now it's just a matter of getting my app to pass through the Summernote data. Right now things look a little wonky.. I can type in the input field and that text will be passed through to the Event object. However I can also type in the summernote field but none of that text gets passed through. At least i'm getting warmer! [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/QupZFY2.png)